# Are two nonsimple closed geodesics in minimal position?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

We know that two simple closed geodesics are in minimal position, meaning that they realize the geometric intersection number. Is this result true for a pair of nonsimple closed geodesics?

Comment: I think you can prove this in a similar way to the bigon criterion. Given geodesics $\alpha$ and $\beta$, fix a lift $\tilde{\alpha}$ of $\alpha$ to the hyperbolic plane, and consider all the lifts $\tilde{\beta}_i$ of $\beta$ that intersect $\tilde{\alpha}$. The number of intersection points is equal to the number of orbits of $\tilde{\beta}_i$ under the natural $\mathbb{Z}$-action... (tbc)

Comment: ...  Whether or not a pair of proper lines cross in $\mathbb{H}^2$ is determined by whether or not their endpoints "cross" on the boundary, so homotoping $\alpha$ and $\beta$ doesn't change whether or not the corresponding lifts cross. In particular, no homotopy can reduce the intersection number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about geodesics in a hyperbolic surface, the answer is “yes”. This follows from the “bigon criterion”.

Comment: Yes, hyperbolic surface. However, there is no bigon criterion for nonsimple closed curves.

Comment: For nonsimple closed curves, the lack of a bigon condition is discussed in detail in Hass-Scott, Intersections of curves on surfaces. Israel J. Math. 51 (1985), no. 1-2, 90–120.

Comment: Dunno and Danny - There is no bigon condition for immersed curves, but there is one for geodesics (simple or immersed). See HRJW’s remarks in the comments above.